# finding "indirect relationships" recursively

Tags: java, recursion

So i have 2d boolean array a, that is supposed to represent the relationships/friendships between different people. Every person is identified through their id (index of the array), if the value for e.g. a[1][0] is true, then person 1 and 0 are friends. If 2 persons are friends their "friend distance" is 1. People can also be friends through other people e.g. if a[1][0] = true, a[2][0] = true, a[2][1] = false, then person 1 and 2 are not direct friends, but because person 1 is friends with person 0, and person 0 is friends with person 2, person 1 and 2 are friends with the distance 2. Now i want to recursively determine, if 2 persons are friends within a given distance, or if they are not. I already wrote this code:

```
public static boolean areFriends(int id0, int id1, int e) {
        if (e <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (array[id0][id1]) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[id0][i]){
                (areFriends(i, id1, --e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

What the code is at least supposed to do is go through id0s friend list, and check for each array entry, if id0 and the checked person idx are friends. If they are the method is repeated, with idx replacing id0s place, and --e. So once again all of idxs relationships are checked and if idx is friends with another person the whole cycle repeats itself until either the "friend distance" e is too high (so no indirect friendship exists) or the indirect friendship has been found.

But obviously this code does not exactly do that, so i would be helpful for any tips what i did wrong or how i can fix my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It will better to represent your data as Graph and then use Dijikstra algorithm to find path between two nodes. In fact, each person is represented by a Node and an arc between two nodes modulate the friendship relation.

With your data module, I suggest as solution :

```
public static boolean areFriends(boolean friends[][], int id1, int id2, int distance) {
    if (friends[id1][id2]) {
        return true;
    }

    if (distance == 0) {
        return freinds[id1][id2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < friends[id1].length; i++) {
        if (i != id1 && friends[id1][i] && areFriends(friends, i, id2, distance - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```